# jQuery failing to find Dynamic Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery working on a number of my other dynamic elements, including elements from the same partial but I can't seem to access the elements by name or id with the one shown below.

To try to access the element I have gone through a number of jQuery selectors, but none are working in this instance and I don't know why.

I have tried `[name=$'value']`, `[name~='value']` and the one shown in my code below (also working in a similar capacity in my other code) and fiddle (`[name*='value']`) but none are finding these elements.

What is the cause of this/what should or shouldn't I be doing?

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqrymf10/6/)**

**CODE BELOW**

**Rendered cshtml as HTML markup:**

```
<div class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <p class="lblStyle">Size(CIDR) *</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="editorRowsRIpM">
    <div class="editorRow">
        <input type="hidden" name="pa_ipv4s[d23c87dc-56e0-4a5b-ab53-2631deb2094d].requestedIps.index" autocomplete="off" value="ff43c12e-d79d-4554-9a4b-b2152946dcdc" />
        <div class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-block-a"> <span>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Allocation type required." id="pa_ipv4s_d23c87dc-56e0-4a5b-ab53-2631deb2094d__requestedIps_ff43c12e-d79d-4554-9a4b-b2152946dcdc__requestedIpType" name="pa_ipv4s[d23c87dc-56e0-4a5b-ab53-2631deb2094d].requestedIps[ff43c12e-d79d-4554-9a4b-b2152946dcdc].requestedIpType" type="hidden" value="Requested" />
                    <input class="checkforcontent" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field requestedIpCidr must be a number." data-val-regex="The field requestedIpCidr must match the regular expression &#39;^[0-9]*$&#39;." data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]*$" data-val-required="CIDR required." id="pa_ipv4s_d23c87dc-56e0-4a5b-ab53-2631deb2094d__requestedIps_ff43c12e-d79d-4554-9a4b-b2152946dcdc__requestedIpCidr" name="pa_ipv4s[d23c87dc-56e0-4a5b-ab53-2631deb2094d].requestedIps[ff43c12e-d79d-4554-9a4b-b2152946dcdc].requestedIpCidr" type="text" value="" />
                </span>

            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <p class="lblStyle">Mask *</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"> <span>
                    <input class="checkforcontent" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field requestedIpMask must be a string with a maximum length of 16." data-val-length-max="16" data-val-regex="The field requestedIpMask must match the regular expression &#39;\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b&#39;." data-val-regex-pattern="\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b" data-val-required="Mask required." id="pa_ipv4s_d23c87dc-56e0-4a5b-ab53-2631deb2094d__requestedIps_ff43c12e-d79d-4554-9a4b-b2152946dcdc__requestedIpMask" name="pa_ipv4s[d23c87dc-56e0-4a5b-ab53-2631deb2094d].requestedIps[ff43c12e-d79d-4554-9a4b-b2152946dcdc].requestedIpMask" type="text" value="" />
                    </span>
</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery with wild card selector:**

```
function pad(n, width, z) {
    z = z || '0';
    n = n + '';
    return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}

$("input[name*='requestedIpCidr']").change(function () {
    var prefix = $(this).val();
    var zeros = pad(0, 32 - prefix, 0);
    if (32 - prefix == 0) zeros = '';
    var full = pad(zeros, 32, 1);
    var octets1 = full.substring(0, 8);
    var octets2 = full.substring(8, 16);
    var octets3 = full.substring(16, 24);
    var octets4 = full.substring(24, 32);
    var o1 = parseInt(octets1, 2).toString(10);
    var o2 = parseInt(octets2, 2).toString(10);
    var o3 = parseInt(octets3, 2).toString(10);
    var o4 = parseInt(octets4, 2).toString(10);
    $(this).nextAll("input[name*='requestedIpMask']").first().val(o1 + '.' + o2 + '.' + o3 + '.' + o4);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using event delegation? Like `$(document).on("change", "input[name*='requestedIpCidr']"), function() { ... });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `nextAll()` get all the following sibling and element `input[name*='requestedIpMask']` is not the sibling thus its fails to find element.

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)to traverse up then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).closest('.ui-grid-c').find("input[name*='requestedIpMask']")
```

instead of

```
$(this).nextAll("input[name*='requestedIpMask']")
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/h1zkt71n/)

---

Since you are create elements dynamically use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$(parentStaticContainer).on('click', "input[name*='requestedIpCidr']", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

Comment: Just tested on my end, not fully working but think that's due to content not being there on page load, tested on fiddle and works beautifully - thank you!
Thanks for the explanation as well - will mark accepted when allowed.

Comment: @PurpleSmurph, You also need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) see updated answer

Comment: OK I shall look into that. Cheers